# Is it possible to create tables in MySQL Workbench using a SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to design a new schema and I have an exisiting create statement for a new table. Is it possible to use the create statement to create the table instead of manually writing out all the columns and types?

For example, here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (
 `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
 `user_stamp` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `user_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `company_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
 `active` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 `first_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
 `last_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 INDEX `fk__user__company_idx` (`company_code` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk__user__company`
 FOREIGN KEY (`company_code`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`company` (`company_code`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
);
```

I want to be able to run this statement somewhere in MySQL Workbench so the table gets added to my schema and then I use it in my diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the `CREATE TABLE` statements to a file, then choose `File > Import > Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script...` in Mysql Workbench (v. 8.0). If you have relations between tables Mysql Workbench should be able to guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Just paste the create statement you have into a query window and execute it.

Comment: do you have to have an active connection to do that? right now Im not actually connected to a database because I'm trying to design the schema before updating my database.

Comment: Just create another 'dummy' database, for your test and schmera changes.

Comment: Ok, that's a different question - your original question asked if it was possible 'to create the table' - obviously you have to have a connection to the database if you want to create a table in that database. So what you want is a way to parse the create statement and convert it into a local schema description... I don't know of a way to do that, though it may be possible.

Comment: basically I'm just looking for an easier way to create tables in my Model instead of typing out every single column